# Error en función javascript para cargar preview de imágenes (ASP.Net C#)

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo una función para cargar un preview de imágenes antes de guardar los archivos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
              var uplImg = document.getElementById('preImg');
              uplImg.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
          }
       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
       }
   }
   var fu = document.getElementById("fuImagenCliente");
   fu.onchange(function() {
           readURL(this);
   })
```

Chrome y Firefox no detectan el error y "funciona bien", pero en la consola de JavaScript veo un error:

> Cannot read property 'onchange' of null (Chrome)
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onchange' of null (Firefox)

Pero IE 11 sí lo hace:
[image: Error IE 11]
La función que se ejecuta en el evento onchange espera un parámetro, pero no sé qué parámetro pasarle.

**Actualización**
Al debuggear veo que el control `fuImagenCliente` no está cargado, estoy trabajando en ASP.Net y seguramente la función está queriendo encontrar un control el cual todavía no fue cargado

Comment: Creo que si simplemente pones fu.onchange(function(e){ te va a dejar de salir

Comment: No, fue lo primero que probé

Comment: En el pantallazo se ve `document.getElementById("fileupload")` mientras que en el codigo que has puesto se ve `document.getElementById("fulImagenCliente")` Puede tener algo que ver?

Comment: Es el nombre de otro control con el que estaba haciendo las pruebas pero el error es el mismo, la captura es de antes de utilizar el ``"filupload"``

Comment: El problema que veo, es que no ese `document.getElementById()` no encuentra el elemento y por eso da error de que no encuentra no puede ejecutar una funcion sobre null

Comment: Justamente eso acabo de agregar a la pregunta

Comment: Creo que mi error tiene que ver con sincronismo más que con este error que marca @Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví llamando al a función ``readURL()´´ y quité la llamada al onchange que tenía debajo, con esto funciona perfecto en los tres navegadores que probé.

```
   function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var uplImg = document.getElementById('preImg');
                uplImg.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ejecutar ese codigo una vez que tu DOM esta ya cargado. Para ello si utilizas Jquery puede utilizar:

`$('document').ready(function(){
   //ejecutar aqui tu codigo
}`

Si no utilizas Jquery, coloca tu script en la parte final del `<body>` justo encima del `</body>`.

Si aun asi no funciona, puedes echarle un ojo a esta pregunta [Como ejecutar cuando el Dom esta cargado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)